# Automatic Weights failing

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to rig a digitigrade model (which is already a challenge in itself), but I've hit an impasse where I try to generate Automatic Weights and it just fails, saying "Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones". How would I go about fixing this? I'll attach my Blender file.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38669/armature-bone-heat-failed and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-error-message and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56416/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-a-solution-for-one-or-more-bones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this instance, selecting all the vertices and doing `Mesh->Vertices->Remove Doubles` will solve it.

[image]

In general, for automatic weight painting, your model must be very clean, with no duplicate verts for example, and not be rotated nor scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Not always the case. However, try to eliminate double vertexes from the entire mesh before applying Automatic Weights. I hope this works for you.