# Bone Heat Weighting Failed. No solution works

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I have an object, that always result in a "Bone Heat Weighting Failed" error when I try to set parents with automatic weights.

What I tried as a fix so far:

- It's only one lose part.
- Just using a single bone.
- Making sure scale of bone is applied.
- Making sure bone is inside mesh.
- Making sure they have the same origin.
- Remove doubles in mesh.
- Check normals.
- Applied modifiers.
- Checked vertex groups, UV maps.

Can someone with some rigging experience quickly take a look at the .blend file and help me out?

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51166

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38669/armature-bone-heat-failed

Comment: I listed all the things i already tried which are the suggested answers in the threads you linked. Besided "do it manually"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to scale up your object, parent, then scale back down (if you want to). I gave it a quick test with a single bone, which failed at default size, but worked after scaling both objects by a factor of 10.

The reason this works is because the automatic weighting system has a hard time with vertices that are very close together. Scaling up spreads everything out, making it easier to calculate.

Comment: wow this worked for me..I dont understand why but I scaled it up automatic weights worked and than scaled it back boom

Comment: you are my savior from the past!! This works finally!! Thanks!!

Comment: Honestly this seemed like a hoodoo magic solution to me, except for the fact it worked when everything else didn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a Decimate>>Un-Subdivide>>2 Iterations modifier on this mesh the rigging will work and it will preserve the topology. If you want you can apply a subdivison surface modifier after it for the same resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I tried scaling up the model delete duplicates recalculate normals and deleted vertex groups of the armature it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for slower computers:
Parent it "manually".

Not exactly easy.
But when I tried some of the above solutions,
my computer was suddenly way too slow to pose the armature.
Parenting it manually fixes this issue tho.

- In edit mode, manually select some vertices nearby a bone.
  (for the object you want to parent to an armature)
- Don't parent anything  yet.
- add these vertices to a vertex group.
- name this vertex group exactly the same as the bone they're near.
- do this for other vertices nearby other bones.
- now parent the object to armature with **envelope** weights. Not automatic weights.
- Now it's *somewhat* rigged. It may require more tweaking.

Yeah, it's not perfect.
But this method let's me pose the object without major lag.
I only had to do this for hair, so it wasn't too much work.

Edit: Before I manually parented it, I applied a decimate modifier using the planar option (8 degrees). This allowed me to reduce vertices without reducing quality, whereas the un-subdivide method immediately made it look too low-poly.