# Bone heat weighting problem

Tags: rigging, error, vertex-weights

[image: Character]

I know high poly models not preferred to rig but I like to make a breif animation with this little guy.

Comment: so where is the problem? please share your file if you want us to test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: even though I compress it, it is around 40mb... Is it possible I send it to you via drive? (I swear on my mother there are no viruses)

Comment: maybe http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38669/armature-bone-heat-failed