# "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" error

Tags: rigging

I am a noob at blender and I am just starting out... I am attempting to create a Halo Spartan Model for animation. I am at the stage where I am attempting to pair the model with a rig, but I keep getting the error "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones". I've tried everything but i have no idea whats wrong.... Here is the File that im working on. thanks

FILE HERE:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzZQFvPOavRyulfpFwzSUnhRzVP-Ipob/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: From the picture you posted we can clearly see that some bones are outside the mesh. For those a solution cannot be found as said by blender.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I tried it with the bones aligned properly inside the model but I would still get the error... from what I gathered from doing some research online I believe the error stems from the mesh of the model.... but I may very well be wrong im new to blender :P any thoughts?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bone+Heat+Weighting%3A+failed+to+find+solution+for+one+or+more+bones

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38669/armature-bone-heat-failed

Comment: Using F3 > **Select Non Manifold** (Vertices), you can find 101 problematic vertices.